# Apple Mail not deleting mail off cPanel server

Tags: mail.app

My cPanel mail account has maxed out at 20GB (yep). I've spent half a day trying to work out what's clogging it up. I've gone through and purged thousands of emails, so my Trash is empty on the MacBook and also on the Roundcube web interface, but I can't for the life of me see where there are 40K emails that Roundcube/cPanel reckons is there. I've done the Mailbox > Erase Deleted Items thing and that hasn't done anything. I rang up support who were useless and just explained the obvious back to me. Any other ideas? Its driving me nuts.

ps. I've just hit the Rebuild option and now its downloading 40K messages. I'll leave it on overnight and see what garbage it downloads but its just a complete mystery what is behind it, and I have to see what the 40K is so I can deleted it.

I do get an enormous amount of spam that I delete regularly but I suspect the deleted mail is not being cleared from the cPanel server and remains hidden from view in the backend somewhere.

Comment: Did you set it up as IMAP or POP? POP mail will only delete from the server when the mail client tells it to. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrmzt.png

Comment: Its IMAP. Its finished the Rebuild and nothing has changed. The 40K files it was downloading were ghosts, likely syncing the deleted files off the client that is not being respected by the server and are still there. I've now found where the total file count is on the Mac client and its 7K messages which seems reasonable over a few years. So the issue remains the files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

OK - after 4 hours I've found the issue. There were 33K versions of the same email on the cPanel server - but it was right in the middle of the 40K of messages so took a ton of page turning in Roundcube to uncover it. They weren't downloaded to the local client so that's why they remained hidden. FFS that was an effort. As usual the support people are of little help as they insist its all somehow the users fault, even though I insisted there was something hidden in there clogging up the works that I wanted them to uncover via the backend.